# Align form in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alpha

with the new Alpha 6 update of Bootstrap 4 the form alignment seems to be reliant on some new classes, I've tried adding the .mx-auto class with the display: block class within the CSS however nothing seems to move it.

This is the code I have, can anyone shed any light on how I can get the simply form into the center of the screen?

```
<section id="form">
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="email" placeholder="enter your email">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-signup" name="submit" value="send">sign up</button>
                    </form>

              </div>

        </div>  
    </div>
</section>
```

This is the CSS which worked in Alpha 5. Now I understand the text alignments no longer work.

```
#form {
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new Alpha 6 update of Bootstrap 4 "*form-inline*" class gets new declaration of *display* property with the value "*flex*".

For you to bring the the form in the center, need to set it to "*block*".

```
.form-inline{
  display: block;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Mamum, that solved the problem. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I tried, but can't until I've got enough reputation, I'll come back and update when I can.

Comment: @andycl1 you already have enough rep to accept answers. Just click the empty checkmark under the votes on the leftside of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

Add `justify-content-center` class to your form:

```
<section id="form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="form-inline justify-content-center" role="form" method="post">
          <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="email" placeholder="enter your email">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-signup" name="submit" value="send">sign up</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</section>
```